# In what order does cmake add include directories from `target_include_directories()` and `target_link_libraries()`?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake

I have two installations of a cmake package in different prefixes `prefixA` and `prefixB`. Now `prefixA/include` is brought in by other dependencies, but I would like `prefixB/include` to be preferred so the package gets found there and also the headers are included from there. The prefix is brought in to the target via `target_link_libraries(mytarget Some::Package)` via that library target's `INTERFACE` include directories. So something like this

```
find_package(SomeTarget REQUIRED)
# $SomeTarget_INCLUDE_DIR now defined, but also linked into the library target
add_library(mylib source1.cpp)
target_include_directories(mylib SYSTEM prefixA/include)
target_link_libraries(mylib PRIVATE Some::Target)   # should bring in prefixB
```

But no matter what order i place the two calls to `target_include_directories()` and `target_link_libraries()`, `prefixB/` never appears first in the list of include paths, and thus even though the cmake package is found there, during compile the headers from `prefixA/` are used.

Is there a system to how cmake orders include paths when they are added via the two different functions, or is there a way to convince cmake to order them correctly for this case?

Comment: Not sure if this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34274943/260313. But it seems you can play with the keywords `BEFORE` and `AFTER` when including a directory in CMake.

Comment: "Now `prefixA/include` is brought in by other dependencies, but I would like `prefixB/include` to be preferred ..." - You are better to fix your environment or parameters, so `prefixA` will **never** be used in the whole project. And CMake provides many ways for that. Once you have **both prefixes** - `prefixA` and `prefixB` - to be active, you are starting an endless game where every your "victory" could be beaten by **subtle modification** of the project, CMake or other packages and environment settings.

Comment: It's not such a stretch of the imagination to want to override a single package, e.g. if you install debug version of a library usually used in release mode.
Of course this will be fickle, but I'm still wondering if control can be exercised over the order of includes.

Comment: @rturrado those keywords exist only for `target_include_directories()`

Comment: @oarfish I thought order of include headers was the only thing you would care about. Do you mean those keywords only let you place your local headers before system headers, but don't give you control about the order of those local headers themselves?

Comment: `BEFORE` and `AFTER` let me alter order of includes added by `target_include_directories()`, but not for those added by `target_link_libraries()`.